# Debian Wheezy to Jessie upgrade lost system personalization

Tags: debian, kde, desktop-customization

I have back-ups of Debian pre-Jessie. I, unfortunately, have no clue how to open them: Also, I would very much like to find the customizations and re-implement them by moving files or at least going between Wheezy and Jessie, redoing it piece by piece if need be with widgets and window setup. I have partially done some already. I finally have my keep on top, bottom, max, minimize and close buttons on the right and the all desktops and shade button on the left. I am still setting up the widgets in the bar (to include the 'pager'.)

Long story short, even if it would say me little time NOW, it will likely save me a lot when I upgrade again. I should also point out I am also on a newer version of KDE. And now that I think of it, that is VERY LIKELY far more important. KDE 4.14.2 now. I 'think' it was 4.7.?

Comment: It would help if you'd say how you made the backups. In general, configuration information is not destroyed by upgrades; if it's system-wide configuration, apt/dpkg asks you so you can inspect differences and choose the new or old versions, or edit them later. Per user configurations are kept in your home directory. So I'm not exactly sure what went wrong in your upgrade.

Comment: KDE configurations are stored in a directory called *.kde* (or *.kde4*, depending on version) in your user home directory, and, unless you formatted your */home* disk, should be still there, you can easily check it. If they are not properly loaded, it means there is some incompatibility.

Comment: OK, I believe that I used Clonezilla 2.2.3-25 and the directory that contains it lists: blkdev.list     Info-packages.txt          sdb-mbr
blkid.list      MD5SUMS                    sdb-pt.parted
dev-fs.list     parts                      sdb-pt.parted.compact
Info-dmi.txt    sdb2.ext4-ptcl-img.gz.aa   sdb-pt.sf
Info-lshw.txt   sdb-chs.sf
Info-lspci.txt  sdb-hidden-data-after-mbr

Comment: feel like I am no closer to solving this...